# Running Scala tests in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, specs2

I am trying to run Scala tests (specs2) in Intellij Coummunity Edition 13.1.3. I am getting the following error:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57980', transport: 'socket'

'Start' method is not found in MyNotifierRunner null

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:57980', transport: 'socket'
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.specs2.JavaSpecs2Runner.runSingleTest(JavaSpecs2Runner.java:123)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.specs2.JavaSpecs2Runner.main(JavaSpecs2Runner.java:69)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.specs2.matcher.MatchResult$.matchResultAsResult()Lorg/specs2/execute/AsResult;
    at components.reports.ReportsDemographicsComponentTest$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ReportsDemographicsComponentTest.scala:14)
    at components.reports.ReportsDemographicsComponentTest$$anonfun$1.apply(ReportsDemographicsComponentTest.scala:13)
    at components.reports.ReportsDemographicsComponentTest$$anonfun$1.apply(ReportsDemographicsComponentTest.scala:13)
    at org.specs2.mutable.SideEffectingCreationPaths$$anonfun$executeBlock$1.apply$mcV$sp(FragmentsBuilder.scala:292)
    at org.specs2.mutable.SideEffectingCreationPaths$class.replay(FragmentsBuilder.scala:264)
    at org.specs2.mutable.Specification.replay(Specification.scala:12)
    at org.specs2.mutable.FragmentsBuilder$class.fragments(FragmentsBuilder.scala:27)
    at org.specs2.mutable.Specification.fragments(Specification.scala:12)
    at org.specs2.mutable.SpecificationLike$class.is(Specification.scala:14)
    at org.specs2.mutable.Specification.is(Specification.scala:12)
    at org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$$anonfun$content$1.apply(BaseSpecification.scala:56)
    at org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$$anonfun$content$1.apply(BaseSpecification.scala:56)
    at org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$class.map(BaseSpecification.scala:44)
    at org.specs2.mutable.Specification.map(Specification.scala:12)
    at org.specs2.specification.SpecificationStructure$class.content(BaseSpecification.scala:56)
    at org.specs2.mutable.Specification.content$lzycompute(Specification.scala:12)
    at org.specs2.mutable.Specification.content(Specification.scala:12)
    at org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ClassRunner.scala:54)
    at org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ClassRunner.scala:54)
    at org.specs2.control.Exceptions$class.tryo(Exceptions.scala:32)
    at org.specs2.control.Exceptions$.tryo(Exceptions.scala:109)
    at org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ClassRunner.scala:54)
    at org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ClassRunner.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner.apply(ClassRunner.scala:53)
    at org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner.start(ClassRunner.scala:31)
    at org.specs2.runner.ClassRunner.main(ClassRunner.scala:24)
    at org.specs2.runner.NotifierRunner.main(NotifierRunner.scala:24)
    ... 6 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is piece of code runnig in sbt, but failing in Intellij:

```
class ReportsDemographicsComponentTest extends Specification with ReportsComponents {

  "ReportsDemographicsComponent" should {

    s"return empty list of $DeviceStatistics for an inexistent deliveryId" in DBUnitTestsUtils(2) {
      accountId => implicit session =>

        val service = new ReportsDemographicsService(accountId)
        val res = service.deviceStatistics(-1)

        res.size mustEqual 0
    }
}
```

I have tried restarting Intellij, `sbt`, cleaning project, but to nu success. When running tests from the `sbt` command line, everything is OK.

Comment: How did you load the project into intellij? The intellij sbt support or the sbt intellij project generator plugin.

Comment: Show us your test code; it seems that's where the error is

Comment: I suspect that you are using a version of specs2 that's too old. What's your version?

Comment: It's specs2 2.3.10. I know it's not the latest, but I work in a team with other people using the same version and having no problems in running their tests.

Comment: Are you sure you have the same specs2 version in your Intellij project? Sometimes when you update your sbt build the Intellij project doesn't get update. This really looks like a jar mismatch to me between the sbt file and the Intellij project.

Answer (score 1):

In my case closing Idea and regenerating the projec setup by issuing

```
sbt gen-idea
```

**Note:** 
You have to put this line into `project/plugins.sbt` to have the command:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.6.0")
```